# Delphi checklistbox array

Tags: delphi, tchecklistbox

I want to change binary code, to checklistbox. When 1 then `checklistbox.checked = true`, and 0 then `checklistbox.checked = false`. I have 5 items in checklistbox. when Tedit fill with 11111 and 00000 it work perfectly. But, when I put 11011, fourth item uncheck, not third item.

here is my code,

```
    procedure TForm1.BUT_2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i,j, k: Integer;
  kode: array[0..6] of string;
//  checkbox: array[1..5] of TCheckListBox;
begin

  i:=0;
  j:= 1;

  kode[i]:= '0';
  CheckListBOX2.Checked[i]:= True;

  for i:=0 to Length(EDI_2.Text)-1 do
  begin
    kode[i]:= Copy(EDI_2.Text, i, j);
    if kode[i]= '1' then
    begin
      CheckListBOX2.Checked[i]:= True;
    end
    else
    begin
      kode[i]:= Copy(EDI_2.Text, i, j);
      CheckListBOX2.Checked[i]:= False;
    end;

  end;
end;
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to work out what you are doing as we only have a partial explanation, and limited code. However, this looks wrong:

```
Copy(EDI_2.Text, i, j);
```

Assuming you have 1-based strings (i.e. are not using the mobile compilers) then the loop variable `i` starts at `0`. You should instead use:

```
Copy(EDI_2.Text, i+1, j);
```

Now, you don't need `j` since it is always `1`. So it becomes:

```
Copy(EDI_2.Text, i+1, 1);
```

And at this point you can remove `Copy` and use straight character indexing:

```
EDI_2.Text[i+1]
```

Note also that it is pointless to assign the same value to `kode[i]` twice. So the loop could become:

```
for i := 0 to Length(EDI_2.Text)-1 do
begin
  kode[i] := EDI_2.Text[i+1];
  CheckListBOX2.Checked[i] := (kode[i] = '1');
end;
```

And now we can see that there is no need for the array `kode`. So we could just write:

```
for i := 0 to Length(EDI_2.Text)-1 do
begin
  CheckListBOX2.Checked[i] := (EDI_2.Text[i+1] = '1');
end;
```

And then we can see that all the code before the loop is pointless. So the entire function would become:

```
procedure TForm1.BUT_2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  Text: string;
begin
  Text := EDI_2.Text;
  for i := 0 to Length(Text)-1 do
  begin
    CheckListBOX2.Checked[i] := (Text[i+1] = '1');
  end;
end;
```

And one final point concerning user input data sanitization. If the user has the freedom to put whatever they like in the edit box then they might well provide a string that is either too short or too long. In either case, the code above will not handle that condition. Similarly, if they enter a digit other than `0` or `1` then your code will not object. You need to decide on how to handle these conditions and code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So I don't need array for this?

Comment: Your code is magic. How if I check (or uncheck) the Checklistbox and store them to edit? Do i need array?

Comment: This is a new question. Please don't ask new questions in comments to existing questions. Please can we finish this question first.

Comment: That said, it looks like you made the same 0-based/1-based mistake again. Please don't just use the code in my answer without understanding the why.

Comment: Yes sir, I'm sorry for the new question. But, thank you anyway for your respon. I'll try the code.